# How to use KDevelop with github?

Tags: kde, git, c, kdevelop

Previously I used VSCodium for my C and C++ programming needs. But I a beginning to like KDevelop more. There is actually 2 things that I'm unable to setup properly on KDevelop: Github integration and remote debugging with vgdb (I will try to figure remote debugging by myself).

Edit: to be more specific When I try to sign in with my github account it keeps failing even when username and password are correct.
I get this when I try to sign in:

```
Authentication failed. Please try again.

Could not create token: "KDevelop Github Provider : <My hostname> - Thu Feb 3 16:55:43 2022 GMT"
You can check the authorization for this application and others at https://github.com/settings/tokens
```

I'm on Kubuntu 21.10, KDE Plasma 5.23.5 (Kubuntu backports PPA enabled to get latest Plasma version)

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu? There is no mention of it in your question or if it is Ubuntu a version.

Comment: Fixed it @David

Comment: I'm having the same issue both on Kubuntu 22.04 and Endeavour OS

Comment: Check my answer @Voii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub no longer accepts authentication with a password, generate a personal access token and use it as the password and it should work.

Reference: [GitHub Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Project -> Fetch Project...` menu item, which provides the `GitHub` provider that allow cloning from GH.

Alternatively, you can clone the project manually and just import it into KDevelop. It doesn't really matter for the IDE where the code came from initially.

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific. My problem is that I couldn't sign in to github in order to be able to push local changes.